# How chatbots are protected against spam?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, spam, spam-prevention

I am currently working on a chatbot based project. I asked myself how to know that this chatbot is protected against spam for two reasons when integrated onto a website.

First, in the case of Dialogflow, you have to pay for every request. Much undetected spam would mean many costs.

Second, we are using different APIs, so a lot of traffic could break some backend systems.

I already did some research on the internet, but I did not find any useful information about that. Maybe the reason for that is that it's not a real problem.

However, I would be happy if someone has some information/insides about that topic.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You queries are valid.

With respect to your first question, I would recommend having a spam detector before you call ur dialogflow.

front End -> Backend -> {Spam detector} -> Yes -> {Ignore}
                              |
                              No -> Call Dialogflow

With regards to your second question, if you don't have too many server, you can use an intermediate queue to store user queries and then consume them one at a time at your backend depending on the capacity.

front-end -> Messaging Queue (like Kafka) -> Backend -> Dialogflow

Hope this helps in clearing your doubt.